# Integrate $\iiint_\Omega{\frac{z}{y+z}}{dxdydz}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Find $$\iiint_\Omega{\frac{z}{y+z}}{dxdydz} $$
where
$${ \Omega}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \ | x \geq0,y\geq0,z\geq0,\ x \leq y+z ,\ 1 \leq 2(x+y+z)\leq 2\}$$

I found that the region is a part of a tetrahedron through which we have "sliced with planes" such that its faces are trapezoids. How should I proceed with the triple integral over this region? Its projection on any of the planes x=0, y=0 or z=0 seems to be a trapezoid as well. I would also like to know whether we can find a more efficient way to deal with it.

Comment: Maybe a change of variables will straighten out the region.  I'd try $u=x, v=y+z, w=z$ and see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that the region $\Omega$ is symmetric with respect to $y$ and $z$, which allows the triple integral to be simplified as
$$I=\iiint_\Omega{\frac{z}{y+z}}{dxdydz}
= \iiint_\Omega{\frac{y}{y+z}}{dxdydz}
=\frac12 \iiint_\Omega {dxdydz}
$$
hence, $I$ being the half volume of $\Omega$. Further observe that the region enclosed by $ x=0,y=0,z=0 $ and $\frac12<x+y+z<1$ is a truncated tetrahedron, i.e. the difference of the two tetrahedrons, and the plane $x=y+z$ divides it into two portions, with the smaller one taking up $\frac14$ of the volume and $I$ the $\frac34$. Given that the two tetrahedrons have the volumes $\frac1{48}$ and $\frac16$, respectively, the integral is given by
$$I= \frac12\cdot\frac34\left(\frac16-\frac1{48} \right)=\frac7{128}
$$